# Not enough permission to enter SQL Server Reporting Services

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, configuration, permissions

I know that this question was asked a few times before, but none of the answers were helpful.
When I'm entering `http://<localhost>/reports` and enter credentials - there appears a message that this user doesn't have enough permission to enter.

I've made sure that user is an admin during installation of SQL Server 2008 R2, then I make it a dbowner in the report server database. In Windows, that user also has admin rights and I'm using IE as administrator.

What seems to be the problem? What should I do to deal with the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First check the site security settings using the `Site Settings` link the upper right corner and then selecting `Security` on the left. Ensure that they are listed as a system user.

Check the security settings on the root folder of report manager by using the `Folder settings` link on the toolbar. You'll also need to check the permissions on any folders that have broken security inheritance.

[image: screenshot of report manager highlighting the security config links]

Useful links:

- [Grant User Access to a Report Server (Report Manager)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156034.aspx)
- [Understanding SQL Server Reporting Services Authentication](http://sqlmag.com/sql-server-reporting-services/understanding-sql-server-reporting-services-authentication)
  -